# Windows Update Agent API - search update by name

Tags: windows, api

I would like to use the Windows Update Agent API to search Update for Root Certificate (KB931125), but I have no idea to search specific Update from Catalog. Could you please advise me how to search a specific update based on the name(KB931125) by Windows Update Agent API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [IUpdateSearcher::Search method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't support searching based on the name, or at least not according to the documentation.  You could search for the relevant update IDs (although these might change if the update is later re-released) or you could search for all updates of the appropriate type and then filter the results yourself.

Comment: I have searched all updates but, I have no idea why the KB931125(Update for Root Certificate) is not in the list. Do you have any idea about the Update for Root Certificate?

Comment: Well, does the Windows Update control panel list it as a needed update?